Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed in Google cloud platform
I am trying to set label and labels fingerprint for a VM instance programmatically, on Java.
Here is how I implemented it.
public  void addLabelsToInstance(String projectId, String zone,String instanceName,String labelKey, String labelVal) throws IOException, ApiException {
        try (InstancesClient instancesClient = InstancesClient.create()) {
            Instance instance = instancesClient.get(projectId, zone, instanceName);
           // String fprintVal = instance.getMetadata().getFingerprint();


            Map<String, String> labels = new HashMap<>(instance.getLabelsMap());
            labels.put(labelKey, labelVal);

           /* Map<String, String> labelsMap = instance.getLabelsMap();
            labelsMap.put(labelKey,labelVal);*/

            String fingerprint = instance.getLabelFingerprint();
            // Add the label to the current instance
           instance = instance.toBuilder().putAllLabels(labels).setLabelFingerprint(fingerprint).build();


            int labelsCount = instance.getLabelsCount();

            SetLabelsInstanceRequest request = SetLabelsInstanceRequest.newBuilder()
                    .setProject(projectId)
                    .setZone(zone)
                    .setInstance(instance.getName()).build();

            // Update the labels for the instance
            ApiFuture<Operation> operationFuture = instancesClient.setLabelsAsync(request);

           Operation operation = operationFuture.get();

            if (operation.hasError()) {
                System.err.println("Error updating instance labels: " + operation.getError());
            } else {
                System.out.println("Instance labels updated successfully.");
            }
            // Print the updated instance with labels
            System.out.println("Labels Count :"+labelsCount);
        } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

I am getting below error stack.
Caused by: com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponseException: 412 Precondition Failed
POST https://compute.googleapis.com:443/compute/v1/projects/sab-dev-avps-1715/zones/us-central1-a/instances/ansible01/setLabels
{
  "error": {
    "code": 412,
    "message": "Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Labels fingerprint either invalid or resource labels have changed",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "conditionNotMet",
        "location": "If-Match",
        "locationType": "header"
      }
    ]
  }
}

After adding label fingerprints still, I am facing issues. How to resolve this?
